# Variable not passing from Javascript

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I have two search boxes for a child check in system that I didn't write. I have upgraded the input boxes to jquery auto-complete. They work, I search by name and then it inputs the id number.

However, when I click "verify" which should bring up a picture of each person nothing happens to the adult. The adult field is optional and it the second field. I think this is my problem.

Update: If i comment out the first autocomplete box "child" and ten leave the adult alone it works. I've been skipping the actual auto-complete portion and just typing a number into the box and I have the same error.

```
<form method="post" action="Checkin.php" name="Checkin">
<input type="hidden" name="EventID" value="<?php echo $iEventID ; ?>">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" align="center" border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>
        <caption>
            <h3><?php echo gettext("Add Attendees for Event: $event_title"); ?></h3>
        </caption>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <!-- Right Side new searchbox here-->
        <td width="33%" valign="top" align="right">

        <head> 

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 

                    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                        $('#child').autocomplete({source:'suggestname.php', minLength:2});
                        $.noConflict()
                    });

        </script> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" /> 
        <style type="text/css"><!--

                        /* style the auto-complete response */
                        li.ui-menu-item { font-size:12px !important; }

        --></style> 
            </head>

        <form onsubmit="return false;"> 
        Enter a name:
        <input id="child" type="text" name="child" /> 
        </form> 



        </td>
    <!-- Middle -->
      <td width="33%" valign="top" align="center">
            <input type="submit" class="icButton" <?php echo 'value="' . gettext("Verify") . '"'; ?> Name="Verify" onclick="javascript:document.location='Checkin.php';">
            <input type="submit" class="icButton" <?php echo 'value="' . gettext("Back to Menu") . '"'; ?> name="Exit" onClick="javascript:document.location='Checkin.php';">
            <input type="button" class="icButton" <?php echo 'value="' . gettext("Add Visitor") . '"'; ?> name="Add" onClick="javascript:document.location='PersonEditor.php';"></td>
    <!-- Left Side -->
        <td width="33%" valign="top" align="left">


            <head> 

            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script> 
            <script type="text/javascript"> 

                jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#adult').autocomplete({source:'suggestname2.php', minLength:2});
                    $.noConflict()
                });

            </script> 
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" /> 
            <style type="text/css"><!--

            /* style the auto-complete response */
            li.ui-menu-item { font-size:12px !important; }

                --></style> 
            </head> 

            <body> 

            <form onsubmit="return false;"> 
                Enter a name:
                <input id="adult" type="text" name="adult" /> 
            </form> 

            </body>


        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="33%" align="right">
        Child's Name
        </td>
        <td width="33%" valign="top" align="center">
        </td>
        <td width="33%" valign="top" align="left">
        Adult's Name
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: You should start with a valid html page, you have `<head>` elements all over the place where they are not allowed for example.

Comment: ^hes right, you have a form before your head tag even loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start with a valid html page.

Some examples:

- You have `<head>` elements all over the place where they are not allowed;
- You have `<body>` elements where they are not allowed;
- You have nested form tags (also not allowed).

Comment: I fixed the header stuff, how can I fix the nested form tags?

Comment: fixed the form nest. that did it. Turns out I didn't even need the inner ones...who know.                                I'd upvote this but I don't have the rep.

Answer (score 0):

The html you've provided is all messed up - body should NOT be above head!. Check [this](http://www.scriptingmaster.com/html/basic-structure-HTML-document.asp) or [this](http://www.basewebmaster.com/html/html5-page-structure.php) out to learn the basics.

[image]